# Adding Vertical scroll bar in a bar-chart (chartjs)

Tags: html, css, typescript, chart.js, scrollbar

I have a horizontal bar chart that might contain anywhere between 1 and 300 bars depending on selection in a dashboard. When there are many bars being displayed, they are too thin. I would like to set a minimum width to the bar and have a vertical scroll bar to see those which don’t fit on the first page.

```
   <div class="row">
   <div class="{{chartType === 'devicesByNetwork' ? 'col-10 net' : 
   'col-12 chartWrapper'}}" style="height:auto; margin: 0 auto;" 
   *ngIf="showChart">

  <div style="max-height:250px; overflow-y: scroll; position: 
  relative"></div>
   <canvas class="devicesByNetwork" *ngIf="chartType === 
    'devicesByDept'" style="margin-top:30px;"  
       height="250px"baseChart
        [datasets]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptionsDevicesByDept"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        [chartType]="barChartType"
        [colors]="myColors"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't set a min width or height to the chart bars, so we will set the height of the containing div instead.
In the HTML:

```
    <div style="height:250px; overflow-y: scroll; position: relative">
            <div id="canvasContainer">
                    <canvas></canvas>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Then add a Javascript function that calculates the height of the `canvasContainer` div based on the number of bars available and the min height of every bar:

```
    function calcHeight (numOfBars) {
            var maxHeightOfChart = 250;
            var minHeight = 40; //setting the min height of the bar + margin between
            var chartHeight = minHeight * numOfBars > maxHeightOfChart ? minHeight * numOfBars : maxHeightOfChart;
            document.getElementById("canvasContainer").style.height = chartHeight.toString()+"px";
    }
```